# Transparent cover on the water surface of a swimming pool

Tags: pool

could please anybody tell me how it is called ? The swim pool in one of the episode of Californication had it. People were walking on it, it looked like there were going on the water surface. Then Hank Moody broke it and fell into the water.

Comment: Off topic, but I believe it's called a ['Walk on Water Pool Cover'](http://tinyurl.com/3qt8zka)

Comment: How is it off topic ? Improving my home with a transparent cover on a pool... Unfortunately it looks that it is done for special occasions only ... And it's half a day worth of work to put it on and off.

Comment: Hey, no spoilers!

Comment: @lisak: Your question is more about a TV show than home improvement. You're also asking about something that's strictly a professional service, with no practical DIY solution unless you've got an engineering degree, dive equipment, and a ton of money.

Comment: Not asking about tv show, just increasing the probability that someone will know the answer, because I've never see that anywhere else

Comment: You need a trick cover to walk on water? It just comes naturally to me!

Comment: My friend has a company that delivers pools out of the box for a customer. I told him that some people have it in US because I've already saw that 2 times in a movie or Californication in the past month... But obviously it's a very rare thing, google almost can't find any results at all about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could but you need to build all sorts of hidden supports underneath.

In theory a thick polycarbonate (perspex/plexiglass/lexan) sheet could easily support the weight but you would have a job anchoring it so it couldn't tip over or tilt and flood. And there would be a big risk if somebody managed to slide under it and get trapped.